# Install Windows from linux mint without usb or disk

Tags: linux-mint

I want to install Windows(I have .iso file) and I have linux mint. How can i make it without usb or disk, using partitions?

Comment: The answer lies in making OEM style custom recovery bootable in Windows. Assuming you've Windows 7, create a PRIMARY partition of size slightly greater than Windows iso, copy all the contents of ISO to the partition, and use EASYBCD the way mentioned [here](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/156413-create-oem-like-recovery-solution-for-laptop/) at step 7. Years ago, I made my own custom OEM style recovery and made it bootable through GRUB, but I don't seem to remember whether I used `dd` too or not. But the link I mentioned is straightforward and tested.

Comment: There is one more thing I would like to advise, always secure in another media a backup of partition table of your HDD before playing with its partitions. I had a rough experience.

Answer (score 4):

In order to boot from Windows Iso and install it without using CD/DVD or USB Drive, you first need to **create a PRIMARY partition with NTFS filesystem** in your HDD. I recommend the size of this partition (***say X***) slightly more than the size of Windows Iso file. After that boot into your Linux Mint, **mount the X** through graphical interface and **know the mountpoint**. If you don't know how to know the mountpoint or mount manually a partition or how to create PRIMARY partition then please search in [SuperUser](https://superuser.com) or [Unix and Linux StackExchange](https://Unix.Stackexchange.com). Open Terminal and issue following commands -

> - Mount your iso to a certain location say **Desktop** by typing **`mount -o loop iso_location ~/Desktop`** where *iso_location* is the file location of Windows Iso.
> - Copy everything from Windows Iso to X by typing **`cp -rv ~/Desktop/* mountpoint`** where *mountpoint* is the **location of X mounted in /**.
> - Once everything is copied with no errors, type **`os-prober`** and you should see this kind of output et al., **`/dev/sda4:Windows Recovery Environment (loader):Windows1:chain`**.
> - If you see something similar, then type **`grub-mkconfig -o grub.cfg_location /dev/sda`** where *grub.cfg_location* is location of Grub configuration file, typically is ***/boot/grub/grub.cfg*** and */dev/sda* is primary HDD of mine.

**Boot into Grub** and you will see the new Windows entry, **enter it** and you will be able to install it now.

#### Note:- The aforementioned technique worked for Windows 7/8 Iso perfectly well. Irrespective of surety of techniques you read, always take a [backup of partition table](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12986/how-to-copy-the-partition-layout-of-a-whole-disk-using-standard-tools) in another media before tinkering with them.