# How to make a bootable pendrive for Windows 10 Technical Preview from Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, usb-flash-drive, bootable-media, windows-10-preview

I want to install **Windows 10 Technical Preview x64** on my computer, and I have downloaded the ISO file.

Now I need to make the USB stick bootable, but I am using Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit (Trusty Tahr), so how can I make a bootable pendrive for Windows 10 from Ubuntu?

I have tried making USB bootable using **winusb**, but it's not working! Is there another option?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-with-ubuntu

Comment: I once [answered](https://superuser.com/questions/892890/install-windows-from-linux-mint-without-usb-or-disk/893043#893043) a question how to install Windows 7/8 without USB/DVD. You may try it. Just use your USB against the partition. Please post the results if it works(works easily for Windows 7/8) for Windows 10 too.

Comment: @Firelord it might work but it's not a good idea to partition the HDD

Comment: That's why I mentioned in my last comment, change the HDD partition location with your USB location. It works for Windows 7/8.

Answer (score 14):

I tried `dd`, but it didn't work. I tried UNetbootin, but it didn't work.  I looked for winusb, but I couldn't find it and heard it doesn't work for Windows 10, anyway.

But! This did work for me! http://onetransistor.blogspot.com/2014/09/make-bootable-windows-usb-from-ubuntu.html

Note that I had to add "--force" on the grub-install command.

The steps are basically as follows:

1. Format a USB drive; give it an NTFS partition. Write down the partition's UUID.
2. Mount the Windows ISO image and copy all the files to the USB drive.
3. Run `sudo grub-install --force --target=i386-pc --boot-directory="/<path-to-usb>/boot" /dev/sdX`, where `sdX` is like, "sdb".  (Not sdb1.)
4. Put the following text on the USB drive, in a new file at `boot/grub/grub.cfg`

   ```
   default=1
   timeout=15
   color_normal=light-cyan/dark-gray
   menu_color_normal=black/light-cyan
   menu_color_highlight=white/black
   menuentry "Start Windows Installation" {
       insmod ntfs
       insmod search_fs_uuid
       insmod chain
       search --no-floppy --fs-uuid <drive_UUID> --set root
       chainloader +1
       boot
   }
   menuentry "Boot from the first hard drive" {
       insmod ntfs
       insmod chain
       insmod part_msdos
       set root=(hd1)
       chainloader +1
       boot
   }
   ```

In the file, replace <drive_UUID> with the partition ID you wrote down.  (Note that when I booted it, I saw something like "no such drive U7A6.." or whatever the id I put in was...but it booted anyway, so hey.)

Drive should be bootable at that point. It worked for me. There are a few possible error messages he explains on the site, if you have problems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Erhannis; could you edit your answer and summarise the link you've provided please? The content may go stale or disappear. Thanks!

Comment: I did this, however, my pc doesn't boot from usb. It isn't recognizing it as a boot device. I've set the first boot priority as usb...

Answer (score 2):

I did that with winusb. To install it, run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight && \
sudo sh -c "sed -i 's/trusty/saucy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/colingille-freshlight-trusty.list" && \
sudo apt-get update && \
sudo apt-get install winusb
```

Then I think you can use this program without my help.

You can try [UNetbootin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNetbootin). To install, run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gezakovacs/ppa && \
sudo apt-get update && \
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```

Comment: Yeah I found one thread with similar answer, I installed winusb but not sure if it works for windows 10!

Comment: winusb doesn't work for w10

Comment: Try unetbootin `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gezakovacs/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install unetbootin`

Comment: Doesn't work at all. When I reboot, it simply starts Ubuntu, doesn't show me any option  to install windows10

Comment: Try to go to bios and change boot priority to your usb.

Comment: It's already prioritized. Is there any other option?

Comment: I think that you need to make windows pendrive on windows because linux is not supporting windows 10 yet.

Comment: Yeah, I have read that on windows official site but I was asking because I have no windows! Anyways I'll do on somebody's computer

Comment: "The current UNetbootin boot chain is not compatible with UEFI and computers that come with a pre-installed copy Windows 8" sayeth Briam at https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-with-ubuntu - which contains specifics on how to work around that.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `dd` command to create a bootable USB stick.

First you must find the device where the USB stick is mounted. If you plug in the USB device and run `dmesg` you should see the location. An example would be `/dev/sdf`.

Next you will unmount the device where the USB stick is mounted and write the ISO image directly to the device.

NOTE: Replace the question mark with the USB device device file.

```
$ sudo umount /dev/sd?
$ sudo dd if=/path/to/windows10.iso of=/dev/sd? bs=1M && sync
```

Comment: How can I know my USB device is mounted on /dev/sdb?

Comment: use `dmesg` command to find mount point of your device files

Comment: You cant create windows bootable pendrive using dd command

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-with-ubuntu

Comment: @ali786 - first read that article clear you can use `dd` command

Comment: I tried the answer and made the bootable pendrive but it's not working! When I reboot my computer, it directly starts Ubuntu, doesn't show me any option to install windows 10.

Comment: @Vengat yes dd command we can use but before that we need to do other steps like creating MBR , Formatting with NTFS, etc...its not an advisable procedure..

Comment: @Vengat your answere is here http://serverfault.com/questions/6714/how-to-make-windows-7-usb-flash-install-media-from-linux

Comment: This works perfectly fine. I have been using dd to create bootable disks for a very long time. The iso contains contains the filesystem. If it is not working for you then you may have uefi and must specify to use uefi as the primary boot and disable legacy devices. I ran into this problem. I do agree that the answer should be modified to look up the location of the usb device and not just arbitrarily specify /dev/sdb. This could be very bad.

Comment: @Apurva Are you trying to go into the BIOS/UEFI and select the USB drive as the boot device?